# Override JavaScript function in Odoo

Tags: javascript, odoo

I have an issue with overriding a javascript function. I am working with Odoo POS and I want to override one of the POS JavaScript Function.

In Odoo **point_of_sale -> models.js** there is a function called **set_quantity_by_lot**. but it written extending **Backbone.Collection**. I can extend functions which are belongs to **Backbone.Model** but not the functions in **Backbone.Collection**.

This is a code of the function. (I want to extend the **set_quantity_by_lot** function):

```
    var PacklotlineCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: exports.Packlotline,
        initialize: function(models, options) {
            this.order_line = options.order_line;
        },

        set_quantity_by_lot: function() {
            if (this.order_line.product.tracking == 'serial') {
                var valid_lots = this.get_valid_lots();
                this.order_line.set_quantity(valid_lots.length);

            }
        }
    });
```

Thank You,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That class is a private variable in module `'point_of_sale.models'` if you check the return statement of that module its `return exports;`

`Export` contains only this classes that you can override one there methods:

```
 exports = {
     PosModel: PosModel,
     NumpadState: NumpadState,
     load_fields: load_fields,
     load_models: load_models,
     Orderline: Orderline,
     Order: Order,
 };
```

This means you cannot override it or access it. What you need to do Is define a new class `PacklotlineCollection` 
like in the `original` module and change the code of the method, override the only method that uses it witch is `set_product_lot` of class `Orderline` that is `returned` by the `'point_of_sale.models'` module.

```js
   odoo.define('techinca_name.models', function (require) {
        "use strict";
        // to access the classes
        var posModels = require('point_of_sale.models')
        // require any thing is used in the code too if there is

        // define a similar class with a little changes
        var PacklotlineCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            // change this part 
            model: posModels.Packlotline,
            initialize: function(models, options) {
                this.order_line = options.order_line;
            },

            get_empty_model: function(){
                return this.findWhere({'lot_name': null});
            },

            remove_empty_model: function(){
                this.remove(this.where({'lot_name': null}));
            },

            get_valid_lots: function(){
                return this.filter(function(model){
                    return model.get('lot_name');
                });
            },

            set_quantity_by_lot: function() {
                // and this part 
                if (this.order_line.product.tracking == 'serial') {
                    var valid_lots = this.get_valid_lots();
                    this.order_line.set_quantity(valid_lots.length);

                }
            }
        });

        // override set_product_lot to use your class not the orignal class
        posModels.Orderline.inculde({
            // same code the only difference here it will use your own class
            set_product_lot: function(product){
                    this.has_product_lot = product.tracking !== 'none' && this.pos.config.use_existing_lots;
                    this.pack_lot_lines  = this.has_product_lot && new PacklotlineCollection(null, {'order_line': this});
                },
        });

     });
```

**Note:** to override a method of class use `ClassName.include`, `extends` just create a new class that inherit this `ClassName`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Everything seems to be fine. The only issue was I couldn't use `posModels.Orderline.inculde({})`. Then I tried with `extends` and I worked!!

Comment: I will check that It should work, if not I will edit the answer to fix that thank you